# Same host UDP packet correlation in Go

Tags: go, udp, unicast

In Go one can send UDP packets using `net.Addr` interface to specify the target endpoint. Some special addresses, e.g. `:8080` and `0.0.0.0`, sends packets using local loopback interface. When received, still on the same host, the message's `net.Addr` shows `[::1]:8080` as source. What is the the easiest way to determine that the packet was sent and received by the same host?

Here's an [example](https://play.golang.org/p/YSBhaqBNoOm) in the Go Playground. It shows `0.0.0.0:8080` (ipv4) instead of `[::1]:8080`.

Comment: the std lib provides a function for that https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IP.Equal

Comment: Your playground code is explicitly sending to INADDR_ANY rather than 127.0.0.1, which is why you got back 0.0.0.0. And IPv6 is disabled in the playground (which is annoying).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `net.Dial("udp", addr)` and eminently closing the connection. Dial also resolves hostnames, which I also needed.

Would be nice to avoid creating a socket, but `Dial` works for now.

Answer (score -1):

`:8080` is not an address, it is a port number, typically used when testing your own http websites on Windows because on Windows you cannot easily use port 80, the actual http port.
This will only use the loopback interface if you use localhost as the IP address.

The localhost address for IPv4 is `127.0.0.1` and for IPv6 it is `::1`. The address `0.0.0.0` is usually used as a placeholder address to indicate, for example, listening on all IP addresses, see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0).

As mentioned in the comment, you can use [net.IP.Equal](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IP.Equal) to check if your peer is localhost. Just compare your address in question to `127.0.0.1` or to `::1`, the `net.IP.Equal` function considers them equal.

Comment: In this context an address is and endpoint address, which includes the port.

`net.IP.Equal` compares two IP addresses. An IPv4 is never equal to an IPv6 address.